# Can anybody help me get rid of the static from my compressor?

Tags: audio-recording, distortion

I got a new compressor, and everytime I plug my microphone into it, there's a lot of static.  It doesn't show up in the recorded audio, but I would love to get rid of it.

Comment: So you are hearing the static through monitors, but not on the recorded mix? Makes me think there is an impedance mismatch or loss of levels somewhere. The compressor pre-gain may be amplifying up noise levels, but you would expect that to flow through to the recording if so.

Comment: What does your signal chain look like? Are you going Mic->Comp->Mixer->Recorder->Playback or Mic->Mixer->Recorder->Compressor->Playback?